# Unable to autoload constant JWTBlacklist, expected /home/sourabh/dev/celebration/app/models/jwt_blacklist.rb to define it (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt

my user.rb model contains:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :omniauthable,
         :jwt_authenticatable, jwt_revocation_strategy: JWTBlacklist

  def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
    devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
  end
end
```

I am using devise-jwt gem to signin for my rails api.

my JWTBlacklist.rb model contains:

```
class JwtBlacklist < ApplicationRecord
  include Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::Blacklist

  self.table_name = 'jwt_blacklist'
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `User` class is looking for `JWTBlacklist`, but your file is defining `JwtBlacklist`. You need to change one of those to match the other.