# NameError (uninitialized constant Api::V1::RegistrationsController::JsonWebTokenAuthentication):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my jsonwebtokenauthentication.rb is in (app/lib.jsonwebtokenauthentication.rb):

```
class JsonWebTokenAuthentication
 def some_method
    #logic of the method
 end
end
```

I am trying to access the above `JsonWebTokenAuthentication` method's in my registrations_controller.rb(app/controllers/api/v1/registrations_controller.rb)

```
class Api::V1::RegistrationsController < Api::V1::BaseController

  def create
      auth_token = JsonWebTokenAuthentication.some_method({user_id: user.id})
    end
  end
end
```

How can we use the class method specified inside lib folder in rails project.

Comment: Please review your question carefully it's unclear for me. What is `app/lib.jsonwebtokenauthentication.rb`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to autoload constant JWTBlacklist, expected /home/sourabh/dev/celebration/app/models/jwt\_blacklist.rb to define it (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542930/unable-to-autoload-constant-jwtblacklist-expected-home-sourabh-dev-celebration)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly if you want to use the RoR framework you are supposed to name your files using the [Ruby Style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming). Also `JsonWebTokenAuthentication` looks more like a `module`, not a `class` for me, could you please clarify why you choose the `class` here?

I would suggest adding the `some_method` to the `ApplicationController` instead. Another option is to add a `json_web_token_authentication.rb` to the `app/services/` but using the same namespace as the controller.